# why is my slim templates rendered wrong?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra, slim-lang

my layout.slim view is:

```
doctype html
html
    head
      meta charset="utf-8"
      meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"
      title= "Title"
      meta name="description" content=""
      meta name="author" content=""
      meta name="keywords" content=""
      meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"
        link href='/css/base.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'
    body
    == yield
```

my main.slim view is

```
    == slim :layout
  h1 hello
  h2 world
```

it renders fine, but my rendered html duplicates the head attributes also into the body tag! it looks like this:

```
html
  head
    meta..
    meta..
    title ...
    ...

  body
    meta..
    meta..
    title ...
    ...
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    ...
```

why is it like that?

(btw, the reason I am using "== slim :layout"  is to enable nested inheritance of templates (i.e. layout.slim -> main.slim -> form.slim)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have wrong indentation in you layout, `body` should be inside `html` and `== yield` inside body so instead:

```
doctype html
html
head
  meta charset="utf-8"
  meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"
  title= "Title"
  meta name="description" content=""
  meta name="author" content=""
  meta name="keywords" content=""
  meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"
  link href='/css/base.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'
body
== yield
```

Use this:

```
doctype html
html
head
  meta charset="utf-8"
  meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"
  title= "Title"
  meta name="description" content=""
  meta name="author" content=""
  meta name="keywords" content=""
  meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"
  link href='/css/base.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'
body
  == yield
```